# An array of integers

Tags: java

```
public static boolean have(int x, int count) {
    int i;
    count = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (x >= 1) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Boolean method returns true if there are at least the given quantity of the given number in the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first count the times the element occurs in your array. Using a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), that might look something like

```
int vcount = 0;
for (int val : array) {
    if (x == val) {
        vcount++;
        if (vcount >= count) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

**or**

```
return vcount >= count; // <-- to handle count == 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for specific element in an array:

```
if (arrray[i] == x) {
    return true;
}
```

Your code returns true if the first argument of the `have` method is `>= 1`